# Expand $(a−b)^2 +(b−c)^2 +(a−c)^2$ , and hence prove that $a ^2 +b^2 +c^2 ≥ ab+bc+ac$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like some advice on how I can prove that  $$a^2 +b^2 +c^2 ≥ ab+bc+ac.$$

I have completed the first part of the question that asks for an expansion:

$$ (a−b)^2 +(b−c)^2 +(a−c)^2$$
$$(a^2-2ab+b^2)+(b^2-2bc+c^2)+(a^2-2ac+c^2)$$
$$ 2a^2+2b^2+2c^2-2ab-2bc-2ac $$
$$ 2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)$$

If I have done the expansion incorrectly, corrections in this aspect would also be helpful.

Comment: Sum of squares is non-negative, so...

Comment: The expansion is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: $(a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 \geq .....0$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the inequality you have to prove by 2, and then take all the terms to the LHS. Notice that it is equivalent to $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$, which is always greater than or equal to 0. Hence proved.